# Is it possible to inject a repository as a dependency in a laravel service file?

Tags: php, laravel, service, laravel-5, repository

What I am trying to do -
1) Controller will depend on service for logic and stuff.
2) Service with depend on repository for database access.
3) Controller will get service as a dependency.
4) Service will get a repository as a dependency.

My service class is -

```
class AnimeService implements IAnimeService{

    protected $animeRepository;

    public function _construct(IAnimeRepository $_animeRepository) {       
        $this->animeRepository = $_animeRepository;
    }

    public function add(Anime $anime) {      
        return $this->animeRepository->add($anime);
    }
}
```

problem is -

```
Call to a member function add() on null
```

which is expected - as the _construct is never being called.

By the way; from my AppServiceProvider

```
public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('\App\Services\Interfaces\IAnimeService', '\App\Services\Implementations\AnimeService');
        $this->app->bind('\App\Repositories\Interfaces\IAnimeRepository', '\App\Repositories\Implementations\AnimeRepository');
    }
```

My questions are -
1) What can I do in this situation to make my service work?

2) What is the best practice?

3) What other ways are there to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor should be named `__construct` and not `_construct`, with two underscores :)
See the php docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

And if you're injecting the `AnimeService` in a controller constructor, Laravel should resolve the dependencies automatically, so it should work with what you have here just by fixing the name of the constructor method :)

Comment: Yea, typos happen for everyone ;) And I'm pretty sure everyone is annoyed when they find out that was the mistake xD